# Project in Android Studio won't start - Activity Class Not Specified

Tags: android, android-studio

According to new IDE for android I decided to import projects from my old eclipse.
Unfortunatelly I cannot run them because of information `Error: Activity Class not specified` This error can be found I user reproduce steps:

1. From top bar menu choose Run (ALT+U)
2. Edit configuration... (ALT+R)
3. Choose or add Android application
4. In General tab choose project in `Module navigation list`
5. Here I do not know what to choose `Launch default activity` or `Launch`

No matter what I do, I still get at the bottom of `Run/Debug Configurations` windows error.
How am I supposed start my android projects?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Please check if your src folders are added into the build path. I imported my workspace from Eclipse by export to Gradle, and by default only gen folders were marked as source files. Because of that, IDE cannot compile your source files and cannot launch any activities.

1. Open Navigator
2. Open Module settings
3. From Project Settings choose Modules
4. Select src and gen folders and marked them as Source folders by right-click on them and select Source

Hope that will help.

Comment: Where do I find "Navigator"?

Comment: @MattHuggins The "Project" tab on the left, looks like the eclipse Package Explorer. Right click on the package title, then 'Open Module Settings' is near the bottom. Shortcut is F4.

Comment: I think it's amazing that the src folder is not added by default when importing a simple project. I'm trying to migrate from Eclipse to Android Studio, but hygiene stuff like this is not making it easy.

Answer (score 7):

You may have to edit the launch configuration to tell it what Activity to run, or if it is running your default activity, ensure your Manifest is correctly stating this Activity.

Click the dropdown next to the Green Run Arrow on the top bar. And press 'Edit configurations':

[image]

Comment: well I know how to add Android Application, but after I choose module, and click on `Launch default Activity` I can't run it. Because of error placed at the bottom of your window

Comment: `Error: Activity Class not specified` My project called `X` has library called `L` with all stuff. This library `L` has inside of it also `MainActivity` class. I cannot run `L` because it is a library, but I am not able to run `X` because It hasn't `MainActivity` ;) Do you follow me?

Comment: I have the same problem.  Very annoying.  :-/  Android Studio is very clunky.  I think "alpha" would be more appropriate than "beta" at this point in time.

Answer (score 1):

Did you correctly imported also your library in Android Studio?

Check Files > Project Structures > Libraries

Did you see your library L?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `apply plugin: 'com.android.Library'` (from module level gradle) to `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`