# Android studio. Module not specified after import

Tags: android, import, android-studio

I use android studio. I import example project from official site

http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html

When I try Run it I get `Edit configuration` window with `Error: Module not specified`.

I read this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16625227/1864033

and mark (in `Project structure -> modules`)  my `res/` folder as `resources` folder and   sources folders as `sources`.

Problem still alive.

Also `Project structure -> modules` say that `.gradle` and `build` is excluded folders.

What means "Module not specify" in android studio case?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have to update your Android Studio Version and try again. I imported that sample without any issues and it's running fine on the Emulator.

This is my import report from Android Studio:

> ## ECLIPSE ANDROID PROJECT IMPORT SUMMARY
>
> Replaced Jars with Dependencies:
>   -------------------------------- The importer recognized the following .jar files as third party libraries and replaced them with Gradle
>   dependencies instead. This has the advantage that more explicit
>   version information is known, and the libraries can be updated
>   automatically. However, it is possible that the .jar file in your
>   project was of an older version than the dependency we picked, which
>   could render the project not compileable. You can disable the jar
>   replacement in the import wizard and try again:
>
> android-support-v4.jar => com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0
>
> Moved Files:
>   ------------ Android Gradle projects use a different directory structure than ADT Eclipse projects. Here's how the projects were
>   restructured:
>
> - AndroidManifest.xml => app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
> - res\ => app\src\main\res\
> - src\ => app\src\main\java\
>
> Next Steps:
>   ----------- You can now build the project. The Gradle project needs network connectivity to download dependencies.
>
> Bugs:
>   ----- If for some reason your project does not build, and you determine that it is due to a bug or limitation of the Eclipse to
>   Gradle importer, please file a bug at http://b.android.com with
>   category Component-Tools.
>
> (This import summary is for your information only, and can be deleted
>   after import once you are satisfied with the results.)

Answer (score 2):

This sample project was not created for Android studio but for an eclipse project. So try to import this project to eclipse, and then export it to a Gradle project.If successful, you should now be able to import to android studio without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

For my case I solved the same issue by just syncing the project with gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this can help you
 Click the "File" ,then select "New Module",and the next is "Import Gradle Project",find the folder of your module,finish.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, it was an existing Android studio project. What I did was to first close the project, and to open it, I clicked on "Open An Existing Android Studio Project" and it opened the project properly