# Android Application sometimes starts the wrong activity

Tags: android, manifest

I'm currently learning android using the book from Big Nerd Ranch. Right now I'm creating an app where I recently changed the startup activity. Now the problem is, that whenever I run the application from my IDE (IntelliJ) either on my phone or my AVD, it starts the wrong activity (The one it used to start on before i changed it). However, if i open the app by clicking on the icon on the phone, it starts the right activity.

I want it to start using the activity "CrimeListActivity". Here is my manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
<application android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".CrimeListActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".CrimeActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Did you close the app. before reopening it? long press home button and remove from list. otherwise thats how android behaves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe check the default Activity inside Android Studio

take a [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612548/project-in-android-studio-wont-start-activity-class-not-specified)

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I had no idea that it wouldnt always run the activity from the manifest.